# Qual è la preposizione corretta in questa frase?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Qual è la preposizione corretta in questa frase?

> - Il bambino cercava di dormire ignorando lo stimolo **di** fare la pipì.
> - Il bambino cercava di dormire ignorando lo stimolo **a** fare la pipì.

Ho cercato su Internet e ho trovato esempi con queste preposizioni. Sono tutte e due corrette?

Come ha giustamente osservato @DaG, nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stimolo/) ci sono esempi con “di” (con sostantivi, non verbi) come “[stimolo] della passione, della gelosia, del risentimento... del rimorso”, nei quali sembra che lo stimolo sia provocato dalla passione, dalla gelosia etc. C'è poi l'esempio “[stimolo] a ben operare”, dove invece il “ben operare” sembra specificare in che direzione debba portare lo stimolo, non che cosa lo provochi.

Comment: A orecchio direi che siano due cose lievemente diverse, e che sintetizzerei rispettivamente come causa e fine. Guardando il Treccani ci sono esempi con “di” (con sostantivi, non verbi) come “[stimolo] della passione, della gelosia, del risentimento ... del rimorso”, e in tutti i casi lo stimolo è provocato dalla passione, dalla gelosia etc. C'è poi l'esempio “[stimolo] a ben operare”, dove invece il “ben operare” specifica in che direzione debba portare lo stimolo, non che cosa lo provochi.

Comment: Interessante, @DaG. Se il significato è questo, a me sembra più adatta la preposizione "a".

Comment: @DaG: E per avere una frase con la preposizione "di" forse si dovrebbe scrivere "ignorando lo stimolo della pipì".

Comment: Sì, Charo: non ho una giustificazione formale, ma anche a me suona bene come dici (stimolo a fare pipì / stimolo della pipì).

Comment: Io avrei detto nel gergo comune di fare invece che a, ma non te la darei come risposta esatta.

Comment: @DaG: Perlomeno gli esempi del Treccani sembrano essere come dici tu.

Comment: @JoeTaras: Veramente, facendo la ricerca di "stimolo di fare" su Google, si trovano moltissime occorrenze.

Comment: @JoeTaras: Ma cercando "stimolo a fare" se ne trovano ancora di più.

Comment: @JoeTaras: Comunque, penso che quello delle preposizioni sia uno degli aspetti più difficili di una lingua.

Comment: @Charo: Sì, non nego che ci siano gli esempi, però come dici, l'uso corretto delle preposizioni è un aspetto davvero difficile!

Comment: @DaG: Mi sono permessa di includere la tua osservazione nel corpo della domanda perché mi pare davvero interessante. Ti sembra bene?

Comment: Benissimo, @Charo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lo%20stimolo%20a%2Clo%20stimolo%20di%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clo%20stimolo%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clo%20stimolo%20di%3B%2Cc0)***  mostra che entrambe le preposizioni sono usate con  una frequenza simile.

- Direi che è una questione di uso e di orecchio quando sono seguite da un verbo. Nella frase che citi entrambe sono usate correttamente.

Nel caso in cui sia seguito da un sostantivo le preposizioni "di, del, della" sono quelle comunemente usate:

> lo stimolo dell'ambizione
>
> lo stimolo della fame.

Oppure:

> lo stimolo di/ad essere ambiziosi
>
> lo stimolo di/a mangiare